# How can I scan transactions on some contract address with eosjs

Tags: eosjs

I want to scan transactions on some contract address and store this data to the DB with `eosjs`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it only if you connect to the node with history plugin enabled.

Recommend way to do it is eos demux. Check it out. https://github.com/EOSIO/demux-js-eos

Update: correct link https://github.com/EOSIO/demux-js

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but could you provide some example how to use this package as I don't see any docs.

Comment: Try this https://github.com/EOSIO/demux-js